# Algebra, rewriting a formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have to rewrite this formula:
$$10^{-5,6-0,4m}=\frac{c}{x^2}$$

To:
 $$m(x)= -14,0-2,5logc + 5,0logx$$

But im stuck at:
$$m(x)= \frac{2logx -logc+5,6}{-0,4}$$

and have no idea how to continue from here. How should I continue ? Here is the answer sheet([answer 6](http://havovwo.nl/vwo/vwb/bestanden/vwb15iant3.pdf))regarding this question. I have already looked at the answer but i still do not understand what they did at the final step of the first solution or the 3th step of the second solution.

Comment: Fine so far, except that your signs are wrong. You should have $5.6+\log c-2\log x$ as the numerator. Now multiply top and bottom by $2.5$.

Comment: ahah isee thanks i didnt see the multiplication there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ log(10^{-5,6-0,4m}) = log(\frac{C}{x^2}) \Leftrightarrow (-5,6-0,4m)log(10) =  log(C) - log(x^2) \Leftrightarrow $

$ -5,6-0,4m = log(C) - 2log(x) \Leftrightarrow   $

Now multiplay both sides with $ 2,5 $ and you get :

$ m(x) = -14,0 - 2.5log(C) + 5log(x) $